# Convert type Android Fragment to MvxFragment

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am updating our code base to the latest MVVMCross library. I am having trouble with an error that reads:

> Error CS0030: Cannot convert type `Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment' to`MvvmCross.Droid.FullFragging.Fragments.MvxFragment' (CS0030) (QualBoard.Mobile.Droid)

Code:

```
public override Fragment GetItem(int position)
{
    var frag = Fragments.ElementAt(position);
    var fragment = Fragment.Instantiate(_context,
        FragmentJavaName(frag.FragmentType));
    ((MvxFragment)fragment).DataContext = frag.ViewModel;
    return fragment;
}
```

The problem child line is:`((MvxFragment)fragment).DataContext = frag.ViewModel;`.

I am having trouble putting together what I should use in MVVMCross version 4 in replace of what was used previously.

Comment: Have you looked into the [MvvmCross AndroidSupport](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport) library? Don't know enough about fragments to actually help, but hopefully @Stuart will find this soon and provide a real answer for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue is you are casting to the wrong `MvxFragment` class type.

Mvvmcross offer two `MvxFragment` class type to match those offered in Android:

- **Native Fragment** - which can be found in [MvvmCross.Droid.FullFragging nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmCross.Droid.FullFragging/) and offers `MvvmCross.Droid.FullFragging.Fragments.MvxFragment`. This class matches to the native Android `Fragment` introduced in [API 11](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html).
- **Support Library Fragmet** - which can be found in [MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V4 nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V4/) and offers `MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V4.MvxFragment`. This class matches to the [Android Support Library Fragmets](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html).

> Error CS0030: Cannot convert type `Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment` to
>   `MvvmCross.Droid.FullFragging.Fragments.MvxFragment`

By the looks of your error I would say that you are using fragments from the support libraries and therefore should rather use `MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V4.MvxFragment`.